# Alternative ways of saying "hope life is treating you well"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

In a letter to an acquaintance, what's the best way to express literally hope that everything is good at their end?

"I trust you are well" sounds a bit too formal?

Comment: If its an acquaintance and you don't want to be much formal then a simple "I hope everything is well with you" -Erik is your best bet.

Comment: I agree.  ;-)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: You have given three options in the title and question yourself!

Comment: I hope life treats you kind, and I hope you have all you’ve dreamed of, and I wish to you joy and happiness—but above all this, I wish you love. (Probably works best if you’re writing to an ex you never quite got over …)

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks "I trust you are well" basically says "I have this established idea that you are well, but I don't really bother about the real outcome"?

Answer (score 6):

"I hope all/everything is well with you" is what I normally write.

Answer (score 4):

I write "I hope this letter finds you in good health".

Answer (score 2):

*I hope you are doing well* is what I normally write.

Answer (score 1):

I hope things are going well for you. No troubles for you and yours.

Answer (score 1):

If both are semi-religious, a simple "Blessings!" would certainly suffice.

Answer (score -2):

Saying *“I hope life is easy on you”* is another variation.